# Where I can find exception or error logs in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, error, error-log

I am new to Magento. Please tell me where the errors are stored in Magento?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **1. After Magento Installation, you should set the developer mode by this command**

`php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

By setting **Developer Mode**, Errors are displayed in the browser and can be seen by users.

> **2. You can check the errors for `var/log` and `var/reports` folder**

Errors that get in var/reports are more detailed.

> **3. This will display PHP errors in the browser.**

You can enable `display error reporting` from `index.php` in magento root directory `index.php`, you can add below code after the starting of `<?php`

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

> **4. Enable Template Path Hints**

The ‘Template path hints’ is a diagnostic tool that adds notation with the path on each template of Magento 2 platform, login to your Magento 2 Admin panel,

**STORES > Configuration > ADVANCED > Developer > Debug >**

Set Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront, Enabled Template Path Hints for Admin, and Add Block Class types to Hints to **YES**.

[image: Screenshot]

**Alternatively, you can enable template-hints directly from the terminal using a command.**

```
php bin/magento dev:template-hints:enable
php bin/magento dev:template-hints:disable
```

> **5. Remove Cache:-** Always remember to `cache:flush` after the changes, this will solve most of the problems and give permission to `var/` folder.

```
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
rm -rf var/generation/ var/view_preprocessed/ pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/_requirejs/ var/cache var/di var/page_cache pub/static/_cache
```

**Hope it helps.**

Answer (score 1):

Logs will be presented in the following folder in magento 2,

```
magento_root/var/log/
```

Each log is intended for capturing different logs.

(or)

You can also check errors directlr in browser if you change the Magento mode to **developer** if it is used in local environment.Initially it will be in **default** mode

It can be changed in following file,

magento_root/app/etc/env.php

```
'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer'
```

Answer (score 1):

See Magento error reports in the 
`var/log` folder.

Generally, you can see 2 files there: system.log and exception.log.
system.log 
Magento 2 runs in the production mode (not developer mode) then it does not show the actual error message on the screen, but shows a generic message: There has been an error processing your request and creates a detailed error report in the var/reports folder. You can find the error report file there by its report ID which is shown on the screen.